# How to create transition/animation on bootstrap-vue modal[b-modal]

Tags: css, typescript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm new to bootstrap-vue and vue.
I'm trying to create a b-modal with some animation effect using [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). I'm referring this [Custom-Transition-Classes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Custom-Transition-Classes).

and my code is like this :

```
   <transition name="modal1" enter-active-class="animated slideInLeft" leave- 
   active-class="animated slideOutLeft">
   <b-modal ref="saveModal" transition id="modal1" title="Save" 
   @ok="handleOk" @cancel="handleCancel">
   <p class="my-4">Are you sure, you want to save?.</p>
   </b-modal>
   </transition>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question, I just want to create animation effect bootstrap-vue modal

Comment: The bootstrap vue modal already has an animation on opening (flying in from the top with a fade in). Have you tried disabling those with `no-fade` first before adding your own animation? https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems bootstrap Vue's modal animations are not out of the box compatible with the transition. Some easy workaround seems to be to simply manually add the animation class names on the `shown` `ok` or `cancel` events (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/ see the last section), like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/g8w2d413/33/

```js
methods: {
   shown: function(){
    let modal = document.getElementById('modal1');
    modal.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove('hidden');
    modal.classList.add('slideInLeft');
    modal.classList.add('animated');
  },
  hidden: function(evt) {
   let modal = document.getElementById('modal1');
   evt.preventDefault();
   modal.classList.add('slideOutLeft');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$refs.myModalRef.hide();
      modal.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('hidden');
      console.log('test');
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<b-btn v-b-modal.modal1>Launch demo modal</b-btn>

<b-modal ref="myModalRef" id="modal1" title="Bootstrap-Vue" @shown="shown" no-fade class="hidden" @ok="hidden" @cancel="hidden">
  <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
</b-modal>
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you for your time and support. It is really a great help. I have just converted your solution to typescript, because i'm using typescript with vue-class-decorator and vue-property-decorator and things are working awesome.